# IOS Swift how can I get the value of an element on Click in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I have a custom TableView that gets data via Json, I have a Button in that tableView named "FullName" . That FullName obviously has user's name but OnClick I would like to get the "Profile_ID" that corresponds to that particular TableViewCell so that I can save it. My code will help clear things up

```
 class HomePageViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet var StreamsTableView: UITableView!


    var names = [String]()
    var profile_ids = [String]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        StreamsTableView.dataSource = self

        let urlString = "http://"+Connection_String+":8000/streams"

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
               /// print(error)
            } else {
                do {

                    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                    if let Streams = parsedData["Streams"] as! [AnyObject]? {
                 // Getting Json Values       
                        for Stream in Streams {
                            if let fullname = Stream["fullname"] as? String {
                                self.names.append(fullname)
                            }


                            if let profile_id = Stream["profile_id"] as? String {
                                self.profile_ids.append(profile_id)
                            }


                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.StreamsTableView.reloadData()
                            }

                        }


                    }



                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
                print(self.names)
            }

        }).resume()






    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func Fullname_Click(){
  // Where the # 32 is I would like to replace that with Profile_ID
        UserDefaults.standard.set("32", forKey: "HomePage_Fullname_ID")
        let navigate = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Profiles") as? MyProfileViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navigate!, animated: true)
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {

            tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            return names.count

    }

    private func tableView(tableView: UITableView,height section: Int)->CGFloat {
        return cellspacing
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let mycell = self.StreamsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototype1", for: indexPath) as! HomePage_TableViewCell
        mycell.Fullname.setTitle(names[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)
       // Click Event below
         mycell.Fullname.addTarget(self, action: "Fullname_Click", for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            mycell.Fullname.tag = indexPath.row


        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear


        return mycell


    }


}
```

The main issue is with this piece of code

```
  func Fullname_Click(){
      // Where the # 32 is I would like to replace that with Profile_ID
            UserDefaults.standard.set("32", forKey: "HomePage_Fullname_ID")
            let navigate = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Profiles") as? MyProfileViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navigate!, animated: true)
        }
```

Notice I hard coded the number **32** what I would like is to replace the number 32 with the value of **profile_id** that belongs to that particular TableView Cell . The profile_id is accessible in this code

```
                   if let profile_id = Stream["profile_id"] as? String {
                            self.profile_ids.append(profile_id)
                        }
```

I just can find a way to pass it into the **FullName_Click** function ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to make a couple of small changes and you'll be able to access the `profile_id` of the user in that cell.

1. Change the signature of the selector `Fullname_Click` to this

   ```
   func Fullname_Click(sender: UIButton)
   ```
2. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method add the selector like this

   ```
   button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomePageViewController.Fullname_Click(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
   ```
3. In the implemetation of `Fullname_Click:` now you have your button as `sender`. Use its tag to get the `profile_id` of the user from `profile_ids` array like this

   ```
   let profile_id = profile_ids[sender.tag]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
Assuming, there is exists a profile_id for each name,

you can access using the index path.

```
@IBAction func resetClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
 let row = sender.tag
 let pid = self.profile_ids[row]
 UserDefaults.standard.set(pid, forKey:"HomePage_Fullname_ID")
 // rest of the code
}
```

**Solution 2:** 
Assuming you have a separate custom cell, HomePage_TableViewCell,
create another property 'profile_id' in your custom cell **HomePage_TableViewCell**

inside cellforRowAtIndexPath, set the corresponding profile id.

mycell.profile_id = self.profile_ids[indexpath.row]

and move your button action inside custom cell so you can access the profile_id property as self.profile_id

```
@IBAction func resetClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
     UserDefaults.standard.set(self.profile_id, forKey:"HomePage_Fullname_ID")
       // rest of the code
}
```